# Margins collapse when clear:both exists

Tags: css

I am reading [CSS Spec 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html), and cannot understand this:

> The bottom margin of an in-flow block-level element always collapses
>   with the top margin of its next in-flow block-level sibling, unless
>   that sibling has clearance.

And this:

> The top margin of an in-flow block element collapses with its first
>   in-flow block-level child's top margin if the element has no top
>   border, no top padding, and the child has no clearance.

Please check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eto7jtnk/3/), where the first-child has `clear:both` and it has `border`:

```
<div style="margin: 100px">
    <div style="margin: 30px; border: 1px solid red">First one</div>
    <div style="margin: 30px; clear: both">Second one</div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both">Outside box</div>
```

But from the Chrome Inspect, its top margin collapses with its parent and its bottom margin collapses with its sibling. Why?

Comment: Take a read of doc from [MDN - Margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing) it explains it better to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The bottom margin of an in-flow block-level element always collapses
>   with the top margin of its next in-flow block-level sibling, unless
>   that sibling has clearance.

`clear: both` doesn't necessarily mean the element has clearance. According to [this section](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#clearance), if there is nothing floating, there is probably nothing clearing either:

> Computing the clearance of an element on which 'clear' is set is done
>   by first determining the hypothetical position of the element's top
>   border edge. This position is where the actual top border edge would
>   have been if the element's 'clear' property had been 'none'.
>
> If this hypothetical position of the element's top border edge is not
>   past the relevant floats, then clearance is introduced, and margins
>   collapse according to the rules in 8.3.1.

*EDIT 1: I created a case where the element gets real clearance calculated, and got the same results. So I guess I missed the point here too. There is also the possibility you found a rendering bug :)*

---

> The top margin of an in-flow block element collapses with its first
>   in-flow block-level child's top margin if the element has no top
>   border, no top padding, and the child has no clearance.

The border here needs to be on the element itself, not on the child as in your example.

Comment: Thanks, @hugo-silva. So my understanding is that: Only if the border/padding is sitting between the two margins (which are to be collapsed), it stops the collapse. Am I correct?

Comment: I don't know if that is true all the time, but I think that is indeed the logic driving the  behavior. You can also use pseudo elements, as in a clearfix, to make sure your margins never collapse. Have a look at May 18, 2011 version - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 0):

While your question is a bit confusing margins do not collapse if:

1. floated
2. Absolutely Positioned
3. Inline Block
4. Overflow anything but visible
5. root element

Your fiddle has no margins set at all for the outside box and the bottom margin would collapse regardless at is the last child in the document.

The other elements are working correctly with margins with none of them collapsing. If you're referring to box 1 and box 2 only having 30px in marging its because the margin is outside of the border in the box model formula so it would be wise to use padding instead as you can't avoid vertical margin collapse with an intervening element between the 2 elements.